# Markov Inequality results seems too high

Tags: statistics, solution-verification

The Markov Inequality states that

$$P(X>\alpha) \le \frac{E[X]}{\alpha}$$

If I flip a fair coin 100 times, I was trying to calculate the probability that there were at least 90 tails in order to determine whether this series of events was an outlier or not. I was expecting that this *would* be an outlier according to the Markov Inequality.

Since heads and tails are equally likely, I stated that $E[X] = 50$ (and that  $\alpha = 90$), which yields:

$$P(X > 90) \le \frac{50}{90} = \frac{5}{9} \approx 0.56$$

This seems absurdly high to me because it is saying that this extreme event could be more likely than not (which would imply that this is *not* an outlier). I do realize that this is an upper bound, but am I missing something here?

Comment: No, you miss nothing. The Markov Inequality is indeed a very weak upper-bound generator.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica There was no other word to explain other than that, and the answer was too short to seem insincere. So I left a comment. Is that a problem? If I had found an alternative that offered a better upper bound than Markov quality, I would have included it in the text and give it to the questioner as an answer.

Comment: You're right, which is why wer're glad to have things like Chebyshev and Chernoff.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica There is a group of users deliberately targeting other users who give simple answers to simple questions and trying to get them suspended from the site for "quality standards" reasons.  The natural response is to give the simple answer in comments instead.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica Meta has been an uncomfortable place for those who who disagree with the organised groups there

Comment: The comments to this question are **definitely** not the place to rehash the meta discussion.

Comment: @MishaLavrov fair point, I’ll delete mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Markov's inequality is answering the question "Knowing nothing except that $X \ge 0$ and $\mathbb E[X] = 50$, how unlikely is it in the worst case that $X \ge 90$?"

If this is all we know, it is *possible* that $X$ is a random variable equal to $90$ with probability $\frac59$ and $0$ the rest of the time. For such a random variable, $\Pr[X \ge 90]$ is exactly $\frac59$, and this turns out to be the worst case.

Your random variable $X \sim \text{Binomial}(100, \frac12)$ is much more likely to be close to its expected value. But Markov's inequality has no way of knowing that. If you want stronger bounds on $\Pr[X \ge 90]$, you should use inequalities that use more properties of $X$.

---

For example, one traditional trick is to take the random variable $Y = 2^X$, which turns out to have expected value $\mathbb E[Y] = (\frac32)^{100}$ (but this is tricky to compute), and use Markov's inequality to find $\Pr[Y \ge 2^{90}]$.

This works much better: we get $\Pr[Y \ge 2^{90}] \le \frac{(3/2)^{100}}{2^{90}} \approx 3.3 \times 10^{-10}$.

Why does it work much better? Because $Y$ is a random variable that's much closer to the worst case of Markov's inequality. Most of the contribution to the expected value of $Y$ is from values that are unlikely to happen, but much larger than $\mathbb E[Y]$.

If we wanted even better results, we'd replace $2^X$ with $z^X$ for a carefully chosen value of $z$ that makes values of $X$ near $90$ contribute most of $\mathbb E[z^X]$. The best choice of $z$ here is $z=9$, which gives bounds on the order of $10^{-16}$, and generalizing this logic gives the well-known Chernoff bound.

Comment: That's an incredibly cool answer, especially the bottom part─the $2^Y$ part─is I've never imagined!