# Chebyshev Inequality bounds where the difference from the mean is less than the variance

Tags: statistics

Follow-up to: [Chebyshev Inequality bounds for the probability of 90 out of 100 coin tosses being tails](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4287522/chebyshev-inequality-bounds-for-the-probability-of-90-out-of-100-coin-tosses-bei)

In my previous question, I was computing the bounds on probability that 90 out of 100 fair-coin tosses were tails. In this version, I'm calculating the same thing, except that instead of a fair coin, the coin actually gets tails on $\frac{8}{9}$ of tosses. The expected value is $np = (100)(\frac{8}{9}) \approx 89$, and the variance is $np(1-p)=(100)(0.89)(1 - 0.89) = 9.79$. So, the Chebyschev Inequality states that the probability of the value being at least 1 more (or less) than the mean is:
$$P(|X - \mu| \ge c \le \frac{\sigma^2}{c^2}$$

$$P(|X - \mu| \ge 1) \le \frac{9.79}{1^2} = 9.79$$

This result makes little sense to me, and I'm not even sure what it means. Is this a correct result? If so, what does it means? If not, why not? Do I need to follow a different procedure, or are the bounds simply not defined for results where the difference I'm looking for is smaller than the variance?

Comment: If $c$ is too small relative to $\sigma^2$, the right-hand side of the bound can be bigger than $1$, which leads to a true but useless bound on the probability.

Comment: @angryavian I see your point... that actually makes perfect sense. Can you add that as the answer so that I can upvote/accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c$ is too small relative to $\sigma^2$, the right-hand side of the bound can be bigger than $1$, which leads to a true but useless bound on the probability.